# Running Process in background in PHP

Tags: php, shell, background

Some Php Process took long time to complete, like several hours.

So users cannot wait for loading the php file.
Please help to find the way how i could run php in background.
It should be processing in the background(could be hosting background or something else)
although after we closed that php.

Comment: Be more specific - are you running your script via web-access? (web-server), or it's CLI mode? Which OS it is?

Comment: Gearman is a framework for handling "jobs" in the background - http://www.gearman.org/

Answer (score -2):

Have you ever tried microtime()..?
Timing How Long Code Takes to Execute

This little technique is really useful if you want to time exactly long it too to, say, load a page, or run a block of code. It takes advantage of PHP's microtime() function.

```
$start = microtime(true);
//Do stuff in here
sleep(1);
//Stop doing stuff
$end = microtime(true);
$time = $end - $start;
echo $time;
```